# How to make Bash flush command history so it can be cleared?

Tags: bash, command-history, logout

I accidentally put a password on the command line and needed to clear Bash shell history. That was easy enough with `echo "" > ~/.bash_history`.

I added the same to my `.bash_logout` just in case for the future. However, when I check history after a logout/logon, the last command I entered is still present in the history file. More correctly, two commands are present: the last command I entered, and the `exit` command from the logout.

How do I make Bash flush the command history to file so that I can clear it upon logout?

Comment: Strange adding this into the `logout` file doesn't remove the last ones.

Comment: Next time this happens, don't logout but kill your shell: `kill -9 $$`

Answer (score 11):

Bash doesn't write its history to the history file until it exits or you explicitly invoke `history -w`. So if you just added your password in the current shell's history, it hasn't been written to `.bash_history` yet, it's just sitting there in memory. You can run `fc -l` to see a listing of the most recent commands, then `history -d` to delete an entry.

```
$ echo swordfish
swordfish
Oops, that was my password!
$ fc -l -2
1234 ls
1235 echo swordfish
$ history -d 1235
$ fc -l -3
1234 ls
1235 fc -l -2
1236 history -d 1236
```

If you've already written the history file (for example because you have `history -w` in `PROMPT_COMMAND` or a debug trap), then do this and edit `.bash_history` as well.

If you want to forget the current shell's history altogether, unset `HISTFILE` and make sure it stays unset until the shell exits. If you want to forget the current history up to this point but start recording, you can call `history -c`. If you want to forget all but the last 3 history entries, set `HISTFILE=3` then (on a separate command line) set it back to your usual value.

Answer (score 2):

The man page for bash provides two good solutions.....which can be put in your .*rc files

1. export HISTFILESIZE=0
2. export HISTSIZE=0

These can also be entered on your login shell manually as well and it will have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks mdpc. I visited a [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) man page, but I'm not clear: do the variables affect the session, or the history file? I want history for the session, I just don't want it persisted to file.

Comment: Then you probably want HISTFILESIZE to go to zero.

Comment: OK, thanks. `HISTFILESIZE=0` worked as desired. Let me give folks time to answer the exact question I asked. If there are no relevant answers, then I'll come back to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems editing my logout too (I made a backup script that backs up my data to a server). I found this link helpful, but it is for ubuntu.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu